# What's the best way for passing data from sheet to parent window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I've got a `NSWindowController` and its `NSWindow` loaded using `beginSheet:withModalWindow ...` used to add an account that is a subclass of `NSObject`. In the parent window controller I have an array of all the accounts, and I want a way to add the object created in the sheet to this `NSMutableArray`. What's the best way to pass the object?

Comment: `[parentObject setSomeProperty:myObject];`.  Or a delegate method.  Or several other techniques.

Comment: (I'd suggest you learn basic programming concepts before delving into Objective-C.  The next great viral phone app can wait a few weeks.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CoreData` and a `FetchedResultsController` instead.  The parent view can automatically update when an item is added.